# What function to use to fill a vpx Image from []byte slice in go using libvpx-go

Tags: go, libvpx

I've search a lot on how to fill the `vpx.Image` but the only function I saw is `vpx_img_read()` that is declare in `tools_common.h`. This function is not available in `libvpx-go` and also the function takes a `FILE*` as argument, not a pointer to byte array.

I did previously called `vpx.ImageAlloc` to allocate a vpx.Image buffer. Then what would be the proper way to fill the `vpx.Image` from `[]byte` before encoding?

Comment: If the goal is to encode an image stored in []byte into VPX (VP8/9) format, this package might be useful  [vpx-encoder](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rwrz/go-yuv2webrtc/vpx-encoder).